# GFCI: 12G line with 12G and 14G loads, 20A receptacle

Tags: receptacle, gfci

I'm replacing a standard outlet with a GFCI in my garage. The line is 12 Gauge but there is one load that's 12 and another that's 14. I'm trying to confirm my best option

1. Backwire 12G and J hook 14 G
2. Use insure connector

If #2 do I use 12G wire to the receptacle?

Comment: Is your breaker for the circuit 15A or 20A? The 14g wire is probably an issue for that.

Comment: First what is the breaker size for this circuit.  If it is a 20 amp breaker, then you cannot have 14 gauge wires on it.  If a 15 amp breaker you are good.

Comment: The breaker is 20A

Comment: You don't want to have more than one wire per screw, and definitely not the "backstab" where there is not even a screw. Normally, you would attach a short "pigtail" to the screw, and use a wire nut or wago to connect the other wires to that pigtail.

Comment: When I opened it up one of the load wires was just sitting in the box unconnected to anything. Just trying to leave it safer than when I found it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

##### Breaker **and** Receptacle Size

You can use 12 AWG wire for 15A or 20A circuits. You can use 14 AWG wire *only* for 15A circuits.

You can use 15A or 20A receptacles on 20A circuits, with the one exception that if there is only a single receptacle then you must use a 20A receptacle. If you have multiple receptacles, including if it is just one *duplex* receptacle (which is quite common) then 15A receptacles are fine.

You can only use 15A receptacles on 15A circuits.

Both 15A and 20A circuits can have hardwired loads within certain constraints, such as lighting or garage door openers.

A circuit is defined by the breaker size.

The title is the one place that says **20A**, specifically referring to a receptacle. That leaves you with two choices:

- 20A breaker - Replace all 14 AWG wire with 12 AWG wire. 15A and 20A receptacles and hardwired loads are fine.
- 15A breaker - Replace all 20A receptacles with 15A receptacles. 15A receptacles and hardwired loads are fine.

The bottom line is you can mix/match 15A and 20A receptacles on a 20A circuit with all 20A-rated (12 AWG) wire. But you can't mix/match on a 15A circuit. So pick which size the circuit will be and adjust other things as needed to match.

##### Multiple GFCI Loads

There are four ways to connect a wire to a receptacle:

- Screw with wire bent into a hook. This is the traditional way. **Limit one per screw**.
- Backstab - a.k.a,, quickwire and other terms. This is a **single use** wire connection, with size specified on the receptacle (may be only 14AWG, you need to check). Once you pull the wire out you can't put another one in and expect it to be secure. And in general they are not considered reliable long-term. **DO NOT USE**.
- Screw to clamp. This is found on higher quality ordinary receptacles ($3 vs. $1) and very often on GFCI/receptacles. This has two major advantages over the traditional hook: You put the wire straight in, underneath a piece of metal which the screw clamps down (i.e., less work) and you can put **two** under each screw/clamp instead of one.
- Lever/Wago style. This is new to receptacles, at least in the US. An example is the [Leviton Decora Edge as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYX30iTxsEo) and [available at Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-Edge-15-Amp-Tamper-Resistant-Duplex-Outlet-White-R02-E5325-0SW/322083558):

[image: Leviton Edge]

I don't know if receptacles with lever terminals are available with GFCI or not. If they are then I would expect them to have one set of line connections and one set of load connections, so equivalent to traditional screw connections (but **much** faster to install) in allowing one wire per connection and not equivalent to screw-to-clamp (which allows two).

But you have **two** connections per load terminal. That leaves you with two options:

- Screw to clamp. Done.
- Pigtails. Pigtails can be used with any connection type. A pigtail is a short wire attached on one end to other wires (in this case the two loads) with a wire nut or Wago/lever connection and on the other end to the receptacle (screw-to-clamp, traditional screw, lever connector or (ugh) backstab.

Note that grounds all need to be together. With a plastic box that generally means a pigtail as there will only be one ground screw (or lever) on a receptacle. But with a metal box and better quality receptacles (including most, if not all, GFCI/receptacle) you don't need a ground wire to the receptacle, the incoming ground goes to the metal box and the other ground wires can go to the box or to a pigtail to the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use 14 gauge wire with a 20 amp breaker. If the garage is unfinished and you wish to use the 14 gauge load, replacing the wire to 12 gauge would be easy enough. If replacing the wire isn't practical, changing the breaker to a 15 amp breaker would be another option.

Comment: The 14 G load appears to be the garage door openers and the 12G load are lights/outlet for the utility bath and lights for the kitchen. The garage is finished. Sounds like my best bet is to get someone to change the breaker to 15amp?

Comment: @JessicaRogers Changing the breaker is in the realm of do it yourself. But not if you aren't comfortable. Hiring an electrician for this shouldn't be more than their trip charge plus the cost of the breaker.

Comment: @JessicaRogers Just note that nowadays there are specific tightening torques required for each screw, especially in the breaker box. If you don't have a torque screwdriver or equivalent, it may move out of the DIY realm.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is out of my realm so I'll call in a pro but I learned a ton and glad I found this issue! Thank you for helping me understand what was going on here